# How come that $g: \Bbb C^n \to \Bbb C^n$ has $n$ eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

In my linear algebra class notes, my teacher wrote the following proposition:

> Let $g: \Bbb C^n \to \Bbb C^n$ be an endomorphism (assuming that $\Bbb C^n$ is a vector space over $\Bbb C$). Then the characteristic polynomial of $g$ has degree $n$ and complex coefficients meaning that it has $n$ roots. Therefore, $g$ has $n$ eigenvalues.

My question is: Why would this be correct? I understand that the characteristic polynomial has degree $n$ but we can have two or more identical roots, so why do we have necessarily $n$ eigenvalues? Is this proposition incorrect or is there something that I'm not seeing?

Comment: Counted with algebraic multiplicity.

Comment: Then we have $n$ eigenvalues but some may be the same? @Wuestenfux

Comment: But if that's the case why do we count $n$ eigenvalues? Let $n_1$ and $n_2$ be two roots of the characteristic polyomial, if $n_1 = n_2$ then the eigenvectors of $n_1$ will be the same as the eigenvectors of $n_2$ right? @Wuestenfux

Comment: In particular you have $n$ roots of the characteristic polynomial, but there needn't be more then one eigenvector (up to scalar multiples). For instance a matrix with with 1's on the upper diagonal and zeroes everywhere else. (The characteristic polynomial is $x^n$.) This leads us to distinguish between the algebraic multiplicity of an eigenvalue and the geometric multiplicity.

Comment: A bunch of other things follow - the eigenspace may be two-dimensional, the derivative is still zero, the polynomial vanishes more quickly near the eigenvalue - that it is conventional to count with multiplicity

Comment: If a complex polynomial $p(z)$ is divisible by $(z-a)^n$, with $n$ being maximal, then one says that $a$ is a root of $p$ with multiplicity $n$, and it is usually counted $n$ times as a root.  E.g. the polynomial $p(z)=(z-1)^5$ has "five" equal roots.